# UTF32 for WebClient.UploadValues?

Tags: c#

I'm using the webclient to upload values in a post-request here:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{

    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF32;

    var parameters = new NameValueCollection
                         {
                             {"facebookID", IngamableCommunicator.FacebookProfileID + ""},
                             {"name", name},
                             {"content", File.ReadAllText(mapPath)}
                         };

    client.UploadValues(url, parameters);
}
```

As you can clearly see, I think this is how to change the request content encoding to UTF32. Am I right? Because apparently, it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebClient.Encoding` Property Remark:

The `UploadString` and `UploadStringAsync` methods use this property to convert the specified string to a Byte array before uploading the string. For additional information, see the `GetBytes` method.

When a string is downloaded using the `DownloadString` or `DownloadStringAsync` methods, WebClient uses the Encoding returned by this to convert the downloaded Byte array into a string. For additional information, see the `GetString` method.

But nothing about encoding in `UploadValues`...

Comment: So is there any way I could convert this into something else then, using HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the UploadValues method for non Ascii Encoding, The internal method that build the request:

```
// System.Net.WebClient
private byte[] UploadValuesInternal(NameValueCollection data)
{
    if (this.m_headers == null)
    {
        this.m_headers = new WebHeaderCollection(WebHeaderCollectionType.WebRequest);
    }
    string text = this.m_headers["Content-Type"];
    if (text != null && string.Compare(text, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
    {
        throw new WebException(SR.GetString("net_webclient_ContentType"));
    }
    this.m_headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string value = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string[] allKeys = data.AllKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < allKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        string text2 = allKeys[i];
        stringBuilder.Append(value);
        stringBuilder.Append(WebClient.UrlEncode(text2));
        stringBuilder.Append("=");
        stringBuilder.Append(WebClient.UrlEncode(data[text2]));
        value = "&";
    }
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());
    this.m_ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
    return bytes;
}
```

so, it use the Encoding.ASCII or WebClient.UrlEncode without set encoding

use HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Just decode received POST content on server side from Url formated to normal string:

```
var postValues= WebUtility.UrlDecode(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(post_content));
```

or individual value

```
var value1 = WebUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Form[param1]);
```