# ISO-8859 encode post request content C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, webclient

I am trying to send a POST request in C# with a parameter encoded to `ISO-8859`. I am using this code:

```
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

            var encodedText = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("åæ ÆÆ øØ ø", encoding);
            wb.Encoding = encoding;

            wb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["TXT"] = encodedText;

            var response = wb.UploadValues(_url, "POST", data);
        }
```

I have figured out that the correctly encoded string for `"åæ ÆÆ øØ ø"` is `%E5%E6+%C6%C6++%F8%D8+%F8`, and I can see when debugging that `encodedText` actually is this string. However when inspecting the raw request in fiddler, I can see that the string looks like this: `TXT=%25e5%25e6%2B%25c6%25c6%2B%25f8%25d8%2B%25f8`. I am guessing some kind of extra encoding is being done to the string after or during the call to `UploadValues()`.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think you're encoding your text twice, first by encoding it using UrlEncode, then by specifying an encoding in your web client. Could you try without specifying wb.Encoding or without using UrlEncode?

Comment: Thanks, I tried taking away the wb.Encoding, it gave the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I think I know what happens. wb.UploadValues does an undocumented encoding itself. I'm not sure though. Can you try without any encoding at all? EDIT: I found another answer. I'll update an answer with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Google for this. According to another question here on SO at [UTF32 for WebClient.UploadValues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561178/utf32-for-webclient-uploadvalues) (second answer), `Webclient.UploadValues()` indeed does encoding itself. However, it does ASCII encoding. Youll have to use another method to upload this, like `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved by using HttpClient instead of WebClient. Very weird that there is some ASCII encoding going on without saying it in the method description at least..